# How change data member's type by making template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Given the following class

```
class Foo {
    struct Bar {
        ...
    };
    ...
    std::deque<Bar> m_bar;
};
```

I want to reuse most of it and add new function for which I need to change the type of `m_bar` from `std::deque` to my version of deque. I think to make `Foo<T>` templated class, where `T` is the type of deque and inherit from the specification for my version of deque:

```
class MyFoo : Foo<MyDeque> {
    ...
};
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this a good idea?
2. If so, how would you modify the declaration of class Foo to make this possible?

**EDIT:** Note that `MyDeque` does not have the same template parameters as `std::deque`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make an adaptor for containers that not fit? A bit modified code below:

```
#include <deque>

template <class T>
struct MyDeque  {
};


template <class T>
struct StdDequeAdaptor: public std::deque<T> {};

template <
  template<class T> class Container >
  class Foo {
        struct Bar {
                int i;
                  };
          Container<Bar> m_bar;
  };

int main () {
      Foo<StdDequeAdaptor> m_bar;
        Foo<MyDeque> m_bar2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

2) If `MyDeque` and `std::deque` have precisely the same template signature, you could pass the template name in as a template parameter of `Foo`:

```
#include <deque>

template <class T, class>
struct MyDeque  {
};

template < 
  template<class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T> > class Container >
class Foo {
  struct Bar {
    int i;
  };
  Container<Bar> m_bar;
};

int main () {
  Foo<std::deque> m_bar;
  Foo<MyDeque> m_bar2;
}
```

1) It makes perfect sense to do what you ask for. In particular, I like to do it that way so I can specify `std::list<>`, `std::vector<>` or other standard containers easily.

---

If you can't make your template signatures compatible, and if you have C++11 features, you could try this template declaration:

```
template < template <typename ...> class Container >
class Foo { … };
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but unfortunately no, they don't. Particularly MyDeque does not take the allocator type, only the data type T.

Comment: I figured as much. That's why I added the unused dummy parameter to `MyDeque`.

Comment: @grigy - If you have C++11, try the template declaration in my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately. But your solution combined with the adapter idea from paper0's answer should work. I didn't have chance to try yet.